# How to use a connected service from a custom Azure Devops extension index.ts?

Tags: typescript, azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've written a custom extension for Azure Devops which contains a custom Connected Service and Build task. I can use the Connected Service when configuring the task via the pipeline visual designer to select a service and then use that service to populate a picklist with data from my API.

However, how do I use the selected service when the task is executed. I need to access the service from the index.ts. The service tells me the endpoint and the API Key.

In the index.ts I can access the Guid of the service using something like the following code but can I use the Guid to get the service or it's details?

```
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');
async function run() {
try {
    const serviceString: string = tl.getInput('TestService', true);
    if (serviceString == 'bad') {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, 'Bad input was given');
         return;
    } ...
```

I've done lots of searching and reading (including the following articles) but haven't been able to find any examples.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops

Comment: Does anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use some more functions from `azure-pipelines-task-lib/task` (in your case, `tl`):

If your custom Connected Service adds an authentication scheme of type `ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-token`, then the `id` of the token input would be `apitoken`, and the code you would need to add would look something like the following:

```js
const endpoint = tl.getEndpointUrl(serviceString, true);
// The second parameter here is the name of the associated input 
// value(s) of the specific authenticationSchemes type (more on that later).
const token = tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter(serviceString, "apitoken", false)
```

How do I know this? [Experimentation](https://github.com/JoshuaTheMiller/HelloWorld-AzureDevOpsPlugin).

### Other Authentication Types

My current experience echoes that of [others'](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-build-release-define-custom-authentication-scheme/) from the past: *Azure DevOps does not play nicely with fully custom Connected Services*. It does ship with a few that cover most bases. Depending on which one(s) you use, the value you pass for the second parameter of `tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter` changes:

#### ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-token

Ships with one standard input:

1. `apitoken`

#### ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-basic

Ships with two inputs:

1. `username`
2. `password`

### Example Plus Suggestion

Suggestion first: to make your code clearer, rename your `serviceString` variable to `connectedServiceId` (or some variation to be clear that is represents the **ID** of your connected service).

```js
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');

async function run() {
    try {
        const connectedServiceId = tl.getInput('TestService', true);

        if (connectedServiceId == 'bad' || connectedServiceId == undefined) {
            tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, 'Bad input was given');
            return;
        }

        const endpoint = tl.getEndpointUrl(connectedServiceId, true);
        const token = tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter(connectedServiceId, "apitoken", false)
    }
    finally {
        // Probably report some failure here, right?
    }
}
```

Additionally, adding the `connectedServiceId == undefined` check allows for safe usage of `connectedServiceId` in later function calls.

### Examples I found helpful/created

- [SonarQube's extensions](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts)
- [Universal Git Tags](https://github.com/cloudpups/universal-git-tags)